# how to return a document containing a collection if the collection contains a document with user id

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a posts collection in Firebase which contains all the posts people make on my app and each document has its own "post-saves" and "post-likes" collection. when a user saves a post it adds their user ID to the "post-saves" collection within the post. I want to create a query to find all the posts that have the user's id in the "post-saves" collection and then return the posts data, but with the user's id being its document in the "post-saves" collection it just returns the user's id.

```
static func FetchUserSavedPosts(uid: String) async throws -> [Post] {

    let docsnapshot = try await postsCollection.document().collection("post-saves").whereField("userid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments()
        return try docsnapshot.documents.compactMap({ try $0.data(as: Post.self) })
    
}

static func checkIfUsersavedPost(_ post: Post) async throws -> Bool {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return false }

    let snapshots = try await
    postsCollection.document(post.id).collection("post-saves").document(uid).getDocument()
    return snapshots.exists
}

//save post

static func savepost(_ post: Post) async throws {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
            
    let postRef = postsCollection.document(post.id).collection("post-saves").document(uid)
    
    let post = UserID(id: uid)
    
    guard let encodedPost = try? Firestore.Encoder().encode(post) else { return }
    
    async let _ = try await postRef.setData(encodedPost)
}
}
```

[datastructure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlmAK.png)
[datastructure image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lifd4.png)

Please let me know if you need more details/clarity.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexMamo ive added a data structure image, simplified the question and added the code that adds the users id to the "post-saves" collection

Answer (score 0):

You're getting snapshot off nested collection `post-saves`. Do you try to query by `posts` with filter, like that:

```swift
let docsnapshot = try await postsCollection.document().collection("posts").whereField("post-saves.userid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments()
```

Comment: ive just tried this and it hasnt worked for me

Comment: Sorry you can try `collectionGroup ` like that: `let docsnapshot = try await postsCollection.document().collectionGroup("post-saves").whereField("userid", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments()
`

By design it'd be better to store saved posts as another collection, connected to userID, something like "user-favorites". Reason: in current version you need to query all created posts to find all favorites for one user, so it might be costly.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the following query:

```
postsCollection.document().collection("post-saves").whereField("userid", isEqualTo: uid)
//
```

It means that you're trying to get all documents inside the `post-saves` sub-collection, where the `userid` field holds the value, of the UID, most likely of the authenticated user.

In the code above, when you are not passing an ID to the `.document()` function, it means that you're generating a brand new document ID instead of using the document ID that exists inside your collection. If you want to create a such a reference, you have to pass the ID of the document like below:

```
postsCollection.document("3iKc...G2o3").collection("post-saves").whereField("userid", isEqualTo: uid)
//
```

To get the content of the highlighted document, if you already have that ID, then there is no reason to use a query. You can simply read the document using the following document reference:

```
postsCollection.document("3iKc...G2o3").collection("post-saves").document("Puut...rM23")
```

So both IDs are needed to create the reference. If there are multiple documents in the sub-collection, then indeed a query is needed. But keep in mind that the document inside the sub-collection should contain a field that holds that UID:

```
postsCollection.document("3iKc...G2o3").collection("post-saves").whereField("userid", isEqualTo: uid)
```

**Edit:**

According to your last comment:

> It hasn't given me any errors but it also hasn't returned the post, I think that when I use .getDocuments it only gives me the document that says the user's id and not the actual post that the user's id is in a collection under.

When you perform a query to get documents from a sub-collection, you only get those documents and not also the parent documents. Please note that the Firestore Queries are shallow, they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from a top-level collection and other sub-collections in a single query. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections in one go. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection. So if you also need the data in the parent document you have to create a separate request. So you can read the UID in the parent document and right after that perform the query to get the documents inside the the sub-collection.

Comment: yeah the document inside the posts "post-saves" sub collection has a field for the users id swell

Comment: ive updated the code that saves the post

Comment: If you're hardcoding the `post.id` and the `uid`, are you getting the desired results?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I want to fetch all the posts that have a subcollection containing the current user ID.

Comment: ive tried this to fetch the posts the user has saved but it hasn't worked;                                                                                                                                                                        'static func FetchUserSavedPosts(uid: String) async throws -> [Post] {

        let docsnapshot = try await postsCollection.whereField("post-saves.id", isEqualTo: uid).getDocuments()

            return try docsnapshot.documents.compactMap({ try $0.data(as: Post.self) })
        
    }'

Comment: "hasn't worked" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: it hasn't given me any errors but it also hasn't returned the post, i think that when I use .getDocuments it only gives me the document that says the user's id and not the actual post that the user's id is in a collection under. ive added another image to my question to show my structure

Comment: I see. In this case, please my updated answer.

Comment: Hey Jack. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a query to find all the posts that have the user's id in the "post-saves" collection and then return the posts data

There is no single API to do this, as a query can only filter based on data in the documents it returns. Since in your case the data is in a subcollection, you'll need separate read operations for the `post-saves` and for the `users` themselves.

To get all `post-saves` for a specific user, you can [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). This will give you all the docs for that user from the `post-saves` subcollections.

You'll then loop over the `QuerySnapshot` result to get to the individual [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) objects, and for each document from `post-saves` load the corresponding `snapshot.getReference().getParent().getParent()` parent document from the `posts` collection.

Comment: how would i integrate this into my code?

Comment: First off: does the explanation in my answer on that there is no single API call to accomplish what you want make sense? And does it also make sense how you can instead accomplish the use-case with two API calls? 

If so, I linked the documentation for the parts that are relevant. Give it a try, and post. new question if you get stuck.

Comment: ive tried this and its given me the error 'Value of type 'QuerySnapshot?' has no member 'getReference''

Comment: That because you need to loop the `QuerySnapshot` to get to each individual `DocumentSnapshot` object. The reference documentation I linked is your best friend here to find things.

Comment: im very new to this, so i dont know how id structure it. if you could show me that'd be great thank you